# Which one is current thread in this example?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm not sure which one the Thread.sleep(1000) is referring to since both threads are running as well as the main thread.

I've tried searching up answers online but can't seem to find anything anywhere.

```
public class Practice {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      NewThread ob1 = new NewThread("One");
      NewThread ob2 = new NewThread("Two");
      ob1.t.start();
      ob2.t.start();
      try {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch(InterruptedException a) {
         System.out.println("Exception a caught");  
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: main() is executed by main thread which is the current thread when sleep() is called.

Comment: try `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());`

Answer (score 0):

A `thread` can not make any other `thread` sleep. `Thread.sleep()` will always make the current `thread` sleep. Even if you called `ob1.t.sleep()`, you would still be calling the `static sleep(long millis)` method via an instance of a `Thread` **for the current `thread` you are in**.

I repeat, you can not make any other `thread` sleep from a `thread`.

Yes, you are right when you say:

> both threads are running as well as the main thread.

but what thread is the `main` method in? Is it `ob1.t` or `ob2.t`? No, it is the main `thread`, which means it will be the main `thread` that is sleeping.

Answer (score -2):

In Java programs, the thread that runs the `main(String[] args)` function is the main thread. When you call the function `Thread.sleep(long)`, the thread that will sleep is the thread that called the function. Take a look at this example below.

```
public class ThreadSleepTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("oneSecondSleeper will sleep for 1 seconds");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("oneSecondSleeper is awake now!");
    }).start();
    new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("twoSecondSleeper will sleep for 2 seconds");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("twoSecondSleeper is awake now!");
    }).start();
    System.out.println("mainThread will sleep for 3 seconds");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("mainThread is awake now!");
   }
}
```

The main thread will create two child threads that will sleep for one and two seconds respectively. After creating child threads, the main thread will sleep for 3 seconds.